# Is there a more efficient way to flatten Date parts of a DateTime object than creating a new DateTime instance?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a series of datetimes of which I need to flatten the Date potion and only keep time values.

Note: The reason behind to do such a weird thing is that we use a third party component that uses Date Part to make certain decisions. Also, I found a different way to get around it but I am still curious if there's a more efficient way to achieve this.

The only way I could think is create new DateTime objects with the same date but with times from individual source DT objects.

This is a simple example of the approach that I don't like at all.

```
    DateTime flattenDts(DateTime input)
    {
        return new DateTime(1, 1, 1, input.Hour, input.Minute, input.Second);
    }
```

as you can see, this doesn't look very good at all. specially when there are hundreds of datetime values.

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this?

**Edit:**
Please note that I cannot use timespan as the third party lib. will only take DateTime parameters.

Comment: TimeSpan time = input.TimeOfDay

Cleaner?

Comment: you can use TimeSpan: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Can you use a TimeSpan / string for your 3rd party component, or does it require a DateTime object?

Comment: DateTime are very tiny cookies, they don't take any space on the GC heap.  It is a value type, it only takes 64 bits.  You can eat millions of bags of value type values like that without gaining any fat.  Don't sweat the small stuff, focus only on writing correct code.  Invoking the birth of Jezus of Nazareth in your code isn't very correct.

Comment: @LDJ  `input.TimeOfDay` also copies the milliseconds, which may or may not be what the OP wants.

Comment: Midnight can always be found by using input.Date.  So the day portion is input - input.Date.

Comment: @LDJ and others, I cannot use TimeSpan I have added this as an edit. Sorry I forgot to mention this earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of `DateTime`, the properties are read-only. This means that basically `DateTime` is immutable; if a modification of the contents is desired, this is only possible with a new object. In short, there is no solution which is more efficient.

Comment: Excellent explanation in very few words!

Answer (score 5):

There's no more efficient way to do this, but you could reduce the amount of typing you need to do by writing an extension method to do it:

```
public static class DateTimeExt
{
    public static DateTime Flatten(this DateTime self)
    {
        return new DateTime(1, 1, 1, self.Hour, self.Minute, self.Second);
    }
}
```

Then code to flatten the date would look like this:

```
DateTime test = DateTime.Now;

var flattened = test.Flatten();
```

It's not much, but perhaps it will help a little.

Answer (score 1):

I think a little bit more efficient would be to use the construct

```
new DateTime(input.TimeOfDay.Ticks)
```

For easy usage (and also changing the implementation if needed), put that inside an extension method as @Matthew Watson suggested. I would call it `TruncateDate`, but that's not essential.